# D Alembert Wave Equation is not Gallean Invariant but Why y=Asin(wt-kx) is Gallean Invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, waves, galilean-relativity, invariants

I just watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdtHAIh-kas) from MIT 8.04 Quantum Physics I by Barton Zwiebach, explaining Galilean transformation of y=Asin(wt-kx).

I have a confusion, are ordinary waves Galilean invariant or not? Because d'Alembert's wave equation is not Galilean invariant. So, this is a contradiction between the two. What is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Isn't D'Alembert's wave equation enough to see that Galilean transformations are wrong?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308566/)

Comment: No my actual question is why y=Asin(wt-kx) is Gallean Invariant but DAlemberts Wave Equation is not Invariant?